# Does Sonos support live radio streams that use playlists e.g. m3u/pls

Tags: sonos

Some live radio streams use m3u/pls playlists, which is a text file containing a sequence of links to the location of other audio files or playlists.

Does Sonos support this mode of playback for live radio services?

Answer (score 0):

We do support M3U playlists as described here:  https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/154/kw/m3u

You can manually add a link to a "station" that is M3U through the Manage menu on the desktop controller.